# Worklight console apps overwritten when same project name, but different contexts

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

I have a base app that I modify slightly for each customer. I have been using version control to switch between customers' versions in the same working directory and restart Eclipse. However, I now want to have multiple versions of the app next to each other (in separate directories). They all have the same app ids and adapter names, but different contexts.

The problem is, as soon as I deploy a second app, the first one gets overwritten by it. Say:

1. I deploy version 1, open it (common resources) -> it shows version 1.
2. I deploy version 2, open it -> it shows version 2.
3. I open version 1 again it -> it now shows version 2.

I presume it has something to do with the app names/id's being equal. I tried switching the Worklight Console DB from Derby to MySQL, but to no avail.

I'm not sure I've tried all possible combinations, but right now version 1 shows version 2 when I click on common resources and version 1 when I click on an actual environment.

This clearly seems to be a bug or a very obscure undocumented peculiarity, doesn't it? Any help with this?

Worklight Studio version is 6.2.0.00-20140918-1910.

Comment: And now, after all the text, do mention your Worklight version and build number...

Comment: Are these apps separated by different projects names for every customer?

Comment: Yes, indeed. For every customer I create a separate project (a checkout from repository). Eclipse knows it by the directory name. I also change the web context in the project properties to point to a separate path.

Comment: So to clarify, this is the scenario: projectA-appA, projectB-appA. Preview projectA-appA, it's fine. Preview projectB-appA, it's fine. Preview projectA-appA again, it shows projectB-appA instead?

Comment: Correct. To clarify: there are projectA-appA, projectB-appA. When I deploy and preview projectA-appA, it's fine. When I afterwards deploy and preview projectB-appA, it's fine. If then I preview projectA-appA again, it shows projectB-appA instead. I can only confirm this for preview, the actual environment (BB10) of projectA-appA does appear to show the correct version.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the report. Expect a reply early next work week...

Comment: I tried this in 6.2 with 2 projects each with an app with the same name and when previewing back & forth I get the correct preview. I previewed using "preview as common web resources" from each respective worklight console. Is this how you're previewing?

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm previewing. My one keeps doing that. I have to remove both projects from the server and redeploy the first one for it to become normal. As soon as I deploy the second one, it's all back.

Comment: Funny thing: I now see it also writes a wrong APP_SERVICES_URL and WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL to the main HTML file, due to which it tries to access another project (which I had removed and I now can see this fail). Either I am doing something very wrong and not seeing it, or there is really a bug.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this still. So from my POV, there is no bug yet. Can you provide your 2 projects?

Comment: if you'd like this further investigated I need you to provide testcase projects where this is reproducible for you and more detailed steps to follow.

Comment: sure, Idan, I'll do this when I have some spare time, I remember this

Comment: Have you managed to verify this?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to reproduce the error in the question. It does appear to be an obscure bug indeed...

I see no workaround other than a restart of the server (a reboot of Eclipse is not required), via the Servers view > green "play" button.

My suggestion is to open a support ticket (PMR) to have this further investigated and possibly have a fix delivered.